# Elasticsearch API insert data from path

Tags: json, api, elasticsearch, insert

The following cURL command is working:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/test -d '{"name":"John", "age":31}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

However, when I execute the following command:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/test -d '/mnt/c/path/to/filename/test.json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I receive the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}
```

This is kind of weird since the content of this 'test.json' is exactly the same as in the first command. Namely: A compressed version of: '{"name":"John", "age":31}'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a file you need to use the `--data-binary` flag instead of `-d`:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test/test --data-binary @'/mnt/c/path/to/filename/test.json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```